# twitter like current row effect in jquery?

Tags: jquery, twitter, effect, mousehover

I am iterating div and edit,delete buttons within it... How to hide the link buttons on mouseout and show them on mouse over exactly like twitter........

```
$.each(data.Results, function() {
                    divs += '<div class="resultsdiv"><a href="Clients\Details' + this.ClientId + '">Edit</a><br/><a href="Clients\Details' + this.ClientId + '">Delete</a></div>';
                });
                $("#ResultsDiv").append(divs);
                $(".resultsdiv:even").addClass("resultseven");
                $(".resultsdiv").hover(function() {
                    $(this).addClass("resultshover");
                }, function() {
                    $(this).removeClass("resultshover");
                });
```

and the css is:

```
.resultseven { background-color: #EFF1f1; }
.resultshover { background-color: #F4F2F2; cursor:pointer; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the children and animate them using [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), like this:

```
$.each(data.Results, function() {
    divs += '<div class="resultsdiv"><a href="Clients\Details' + this.ClientId + 
            '">Edit</a><br/><a href="Clients\Details' + this.ClientId + 
            '">Delete</a></div>';
});
$("#ResultsDiv").append(divs);
$(".resultsdiv:even").addClass("resultseven");
$(".resultsdiv").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("resultshover").children('a').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("resultshover").children('a').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
});
```

Or, the shorter version using [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), hide them initially in CSS and do this:

```
$(".resultsdiv").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("resultshover")
           .children('a').stop(true, true).animate({opacity: 'toggle');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the children and hide them

```
$.each(data.Results, function() {
    divs += '<div class="resultsdiv"><a href="Clients/Details' + this.ClientId +     '">Edit</a><br/><a href="Clients/Details' + this.ClientId + '">Delete</a></div>';
});
$("#ResultsDiv").append(divs);
$(".resultsdiv:even").addClass("resultseven");
$(".resultsdiv").children().hide();
$(".resultsdiv").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("resultshover");
    $(this).children().show();
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("resultshover");
    $(this).children().hide();
});
```

Comment: 2 things..you're hiding them on hover, so it's reverse, and `$(this).children().each(function(){ $(this).hide(); });` can just be `$(this).children().hide();`, or chained with the `.addClass()` above, not creating an extra jQuery object :)

Answer (score 0):

you could,

```
$.each(data.Results, function() {
    var divs = '<div class="resultsdiv"><a href="Clients\Details' + this.ClientId + '">Edit</a><br/><a href="Clients\Details' + this.ClientId + '">Delete</a></div>';
    $(divs).hide();
    $(this).append(divs);
    $('.resultdiv:even').addClass('resultseven');
    $(this).hover(function() {
            $(this).find('.resultsdiv').show().addClass('resultshover');
        }, 
        function() {
            $(this).find('.resultsdiv').hide().removeClass('resultshover');
        }
    );
});
```

i am assuming that your `data.Results` are list of elements. maybe `li`